# Which chapter/version of One Punch Man the battle between Tank Top Master and one of Bofoi's drone is in?

Tags: one-punch-man

A One Punch Man wikia states there is a battle between Tank Top Master and One of Bofoi's drone. Which chapter/version of One Punch Man (webcomic/manga/audiobooks) is this battle in?

Answer (score 2):

The Battle between Tank Top Master and one of Bofoi's drone happened in **Vol 7 Bonus Manga 1: Big Construction**.

As for their battle:

> The association thought they were under attack because of Bofoi's Drone, at that time Tank top master and other tank top heroes is at the hero association so they are deployed to "defend" their base.

---

> [image: Bofoi's Drone comes in the scene]
>  [image: Tank Top Master and his crew are sent out]
>  [image: Bofoi Talks to Tank Top Master]
>  [image: Bofoi's drone comes for the construction]